# cannot be resolved errors

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Simply trying to change the text on the tabs for android app.   Who knew it would be this much trouble.  how to resolve 'cannot be resolved' & 'cannot be resolved or is not a field' errors for mTabHost, tabs_bg and tabsText

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tabs extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "List");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Map");
}

private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
    View tabview = createTabViewe(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
    });
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tabs, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the exact stack trace error you are getting ?

Comment: Please take a look on basic programming in Java. Then try to deal with Android.

Comment: in java you are supposed to declare your variables, you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `mTabHost`

```
TabHost mTabHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

`tabs_bg`  is a layout. Do you have `tabs_bg.xml` in your layout folder. Also you need to check if you have a textview with id `tabsText` in tabs_bg.xml